# Python - column slice of list of list matrix

Tags: python, list, slice

Given a list of lists like

```
a = [["a","b","c"],
     ["d","e","f"],
     ["g","h","i"]]
```

how can I efficiently get a single column (e.g. ["b","e","h"]) or a slice of a column (e.g. ["e","h"])? Unfortunately I can't switch to numpy...

Comment: If you cant use any packages you could always extract element by element, not efficiently but it works..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an efficient way:

```
import operator

def get_column(list_, n):
    return map(operator.itemgetter(n), list_)
```

You may then convert the output to a list using `list()` or slice the object. The returned object is a map object (basically a generator) in Python 3 and a new list in Python 2.

Comment: Is s a reference to some part of a, or just a new list?

Comment: The returned object is a generator containing all n'th items of the list

Comment: the returned object will be a list

Comment: @user1403546: Note that `map` returns a generator in Python 3, but it returns a list in Python 2.  In either case, the returned entity _won't_ act like a reference to the original `a` list. However, you can get reference-like behaviour by making each item in `a` a one element list: `a = [[["a"],["b"],["c"]],` etc. BTW, you can transpose a 2D list by `zip(*a)`, although the inner lists will become tuples.